# Is there a userscript which keeps track of the questions that I use as dup-targets?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, userscript

I'm just wondering if someone has a userscript that keeps track of the links that one uses when closing questions as duplicate. The main purpose is to avoid having to manually create (and maintain) that list. Instead, have the script update the list automatically every time I close a question as duplicate. Right now, one has to either keep a list of frequent dup-targets bookmarked or just go look for them every time.

The ability to edit the list would be a nice-to-have, but it's not necessary.

Comment: This was posted as a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411791/making-canonical-answers-easier-to-find#comment869928_411791) by [wim](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) "Check out the excellent stack app [Duplicate Target Manager](https://stackapps.com/questions/8061/duplicate-target-manager)"

Comment: @Unconsidered Thanks, I'll check it out. It's weird how I had this question in mind for a couple of weeks and only decided to post it today when someone else just asked about more or less the same thing.

Comment: Every time I need something as a script I search on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) first. If it's not there, I'll try to make it :)

Comment: I get pretty good results just using my bookmarks.